# O(m+n) complex algorithm for shortest path in acyclic graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, big-o, shortest-path, directed-acyclic-graphs

What's a good algorithm that solves the single-source-shortest path problem for a given acyclic (no cyclec) graph in time O(m + n).

My attempt was to do Dijkstra's Algorithm with a fibonacci heap, but that's `O(m + nlogn)`.

Comment: Which results did your favorite search engine give?

Comment: Didn't find any O(m+n), best case I found was Dijkstra with Fibonacci which was O(M + n log n)

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) and [Dynamic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

First, topological sort the graph. That's `O(n+m)`.

Then, follow the recursive formula:

```
D(source) = 0
D(u) = infinity    if u is before source in the topological sort
D(u) = min { D(v) + w(v,u) | for each edge (v,u) }
```

Using DP techniques for the above recursive formula is `O(n+m)` as well

Since you have a topological sort of the graph, the Dynamic Programming will go in order of the topological sort, and when you process some node - all dependencies have already been calculated.

Comment: Thank you, I will research topological sort!